# Difference between GROUP BY HAVING and SELECT MAX() GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

I'm new to SQL and getting confused by the difference in the following two queries:

> SELECT MAX(version), * FROM table WHERE primary_key = @key GROUP BY location
>
> SELECT version, * FROM table WHERE primary_key = @key GROUP BY location HAVING version = MAX(version)

Assuming that the table looks like something like this:

```
primary_key | version | location | data
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, both queries select the max version entry within each location (among those that have @key as primary key). So is there any difference between the two queries? Or is the difference just on performance?

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3469351/The-HAVING-and-GROUP-BY-SQL-clauses.htm

Comment: Nothing. They both produce the same syntax error.

Comment: @mohan111 The article is not very good, it uses "different logical" approaches to outline a difference between having and group by... So, the result is different obviously. (With `group by` it's just looking at `copies_in_stock`, with `having` it's referencing `max` (alias of `MAX(copies_in_stock)`).. If he would use `FROM writer WHERE MAX(copies_in_stock) > 5 GROUP BY poet;`instead, he would get the same result as if a `having`-clause is used on the alias of the aggregation over `copies_in_stock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed  the table name
the use of * star (all columns) when you are using aggregation function is deprecated  and in most db is not allowed

```
SELECT MAX(version) 
FROM your_table  
WHERE primary_key = @key 
GROUP BY location

SELECT version
FROM your_table
WHERE primary_key = @key 
GROUP BY location 
HAVING version = MAX(version)
```

the two qyery are different because in the second  the resulting query is filter for match the having condition

having work ever on the result of a query (instead where work directly on the row source for the query )
and yes the secondo is more slow that the first  ... is most case the difference could be not appreciable

Comment: Thanks for making the point about * . By using *, I was trying to focus on the rest of the columns selected in the two queries: If we select more than one columns in the above example (e.g., version, data), is it guaranteed that the 'data' selected is in the same row as where the max transaction_version happens?

Comment: You mean if a column is not in group by is in select list ... Then in this case is not garanteed  that the resulting values is the same of the row where you have the aggegated  result  .. (normally is showd the first encontered 
 by the query  fetching  ) and is for this reason that the use of *  or the use of column not in group by is depreacated  and in most db is not allowed ...hope i'm clear  ..

Comment: Yes you were! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link, may be useful:
http://www.dofactory.com/sql/group-by